# convertir números a diversos sistemas numéricos(bin,dec,Hexa,octa,base N)

Tags: java, poo, java-swing

necesito saber si hay alguna función que me ayude a realizar la conversión de los diferentes sistemas numéricos en JAVA, o en su caso los algoritmos de cada uno de ellos.

El programa debe permitir convertir a los distintos tipos de bases automáticamente en cada recuadro.

```
package maya;
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class Maya extends JFrame {
  static int ANCHO =375;
  static int ALTO = 300;
  private final JTextField bin,octo,hexa,dec,basen;
  JButton limpiar = new javax.swing.JButton();
  public Maya(){


    setLayout(new GridLayout(6,2,10,10));   
    add(new JLabel("Bin")); 
    add(bin=new JTextField("")); 
    add(new JLabel("Octo")); 
    add(octo=new JTextField("")); 
    add(new JLabel("Hexa"));   
    add(hexa =new JTextField("")); 
    add(new JLabel("Dec"));     
    add(dec=new JTextField("")); 
    add(new JLabel("Base N")); 
    add(basen=new JTextField("")); 
    add(new JLabel("N =")); 
    add(limpiar=new JButton("Limpiar"));  


    setSize(ANCHO,ALTO);     
    setVisible(true); 

    bin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String texto = (dec.getText());//meternoa estring
            int potencia = Integer.parseInt(texto);//convertir a entero
            for(int i=potencia;i<=0;i--){
               int bina= potencia%2;

            }
            octo.setText(bin.getText().toString());
            hexa.setText(bin.getText().toString());
            dec.setText(bin.getText().toString());

            basen.setText(bin.getText().toString());                            
        }

    });
     octo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            bin.setText(octo.getText().toString());
            hexa.setText(octo.getText().toString());
            dec.setText(octo.getText().toString());
            basen.setText(octo.getText().toString());                            
        }           
    });
     hexa.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            bin.setText(hexa.getText().toString());
            octo.setText(hexa.getText().toString());
            dec.setText(hexa.getText().toString());
            basen.setText(hexa.getText().toString());                            
        }           
    });
```

en esta parte ya e agregado la opcion de decimal a binario.

```
     dec.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


            String texto = (dec.getText());//meterlo a String
            int potencia = Integer.parseInt(texto);//convertir a entero
            String binario = Integer.toBinaryString(potencia);
            String cadena = String.valueOf(binario);//convertir a string
            bin.setText(dec.getText().toString());
            bin.setText(cadena);

            octo.setText(dec.getText().toString());

            hexa.setText(dec.getText().toString());
            basen.setText(dec.getText().toString());                            
        }           
    });
     basen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            bin.setText(basen.getText().toString());
            octo.setText(basen.getText().toString());
            hexa.setText(basen.getText().toString());
            dec.setText(basen.getText().toString());                            
        }           
    });
     limpiar.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            revalidate();
        }

     });

}





public static void main(String[] args) {

     Maya miMarco = new Maya();     
     miMarco.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Se pueden utilizar estos métodos:

Integer.toHexString(n).toUpperCase(); convierte decimal a Hexa

Integer.toOctalString(int i); convierte decimal a octal

Integer.toBinaryString (int i); convierte decimal a bin

int num=Integer.parseInt(texto,2);//bin a decimal

Aun no conosco la manera de convertir de octal a hexa, o octal a decimal sin utilizar grandes algoritmos.

Fuente:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString(int)